# Selecting data from a table by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
<div class="widget-content">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Tel</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Action</th>                             
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $allcontacts=$contact->getallcontacts("name",$_SESSION['username']);
            if($allcontacts!=null)

            foreach($allcontacts as $value){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value[1]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $value[2]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $value[3]; ?></td>
                <td class="td-actions">
                    <a href="?IDD=<?php echo $value[0]."&owner=".$_SESSION['username'];?>">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>                                       
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="eb" onClick="fillinfo();" data-uid="<?php echo $value[0]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>                                        
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

I want to get each row data when the edit button of that row being clicked! but I don't know how to find out which row's edit button has been clicked!
Edit button : .eb

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/29657/)**.

You have to attach click event to the edit link using class `.eb` or also using `.glyphicon-edit` class, then you could use `closest('tr')` or `parents('tr')` with current clicked element `$(this)` to refer to parent `tr` of the clicked edit, like :

```
$('body').on('click', '.glyphicon-edit', function(){
    var clicked_row = $(this).closest('tr');
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.glyphicon-edit', function(){
  var clicked_row = $(this).closest('tr');

  console.log( clicked_row.html() );
})
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="widget-content">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Tel</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Action</th>                             
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>value[0]</td>
        <td>value[1]</td>
        <td>$value[2];</td>
        <td>$value[3];</td>
        <td class="td-actions">
          <a href="">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="eb" data-uid="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>                
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>value[00]</td>
        <td>value[11]</td>
        <td>$value[22];</td>
        <td>$value[33];</td>
        <td class="td-actions">
          <a href="">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="eb" data-uid="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>                
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>value[000]</td>
        <td>value[111]</td>
        <td>$value[222];</td>
        <td>$value[333];</td>
        <td class="td-actions">
          <a href="">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="eb" data-uid="" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>                
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Its very helpful! but it takes everything in tr element that I don't need them! I need to get each row with separated values.